# C program for salary increment calculation using structure

Tags: c, structure

I would like to write a code for a C program that will:

1. Create a structure that will store the employee details.
2. Insert 5 different records of employees into the database.
3. Update the salary by adding a 10% increment if the years of service
   is 10 years and more. Otherwise, add a 7% increment.
4. Display the data for all employees.

My coding has satisfied item 1,2 and 4. For item 3 i have no idea how to write the coding. Can anyone enlighten me?

Below the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
typedef struct{ 
    char employee_name[30];
    int employee_number;
    int salary;
    int service_year 
} Employee;
 
int main()
{
    int i, n=5;
 
    Employee employees[n];
 
    //Taking each employee detail as input
 
    printf("Enter %d Employee Details \n \n",n);
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
 
        printf("Employee %d:- \n",i+1);
        //Name
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s",employees[i].employee_name);
        //ID
        printf("Id: ");
        scanf("%d",&employees[i].employee_number);
        //Salary
        printf("Salary: ");
        scanf("%d",&employees[i].salary);
        //Year of service_year
        printf("Year of Service: ");
        scanf("%d",&employees[i].service_year);
    }
 
    //Displaying Employee details
 
    printf("-------------- All Employees Details ---------------\n");
 
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
 
        printf("Employee Name \t: ");
        printf("%s \n",employees[i].employee_name);
 
        printf("Employee Number \t: ");
        printf("%d \n",employees[i].employee_number);
 
        printf("Salary \t: ");
        printf("%d \n",employees[i].salary);
        
        printf("Year of Service \t: ");
        printf("%d \n",employees[i].service_year);
 
        printf("\n");
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about if/else conditions. In for loop for printing details you can check for salary conditions and update salary if it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For item 3 i have no idea how to write the coding.
> Update the salary by adding a 10% increment if the years of service is 10 years and more. Otherwise, add a 7% increment.

I'd avoid floating point math for an integer problem with its [subtle problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316347/c-program-for-salary-increment-calculation-using-structure/63317037#comment111961283_63316501).

Add helper functions to calculate the salary increase.

A key part of programming is to divide the task into manageable helper functions.  Note the two below each handle a separate aspect of the salary adjustment.  Easy enough to adjust should next years adjusts taken on a more complex calculation and not mess up other code.

```
int increase_percent(int salary, int percent) {
  int half = percent >= 0 ? 100/2 : -100/2;
  return (salary * percent + half)/100; // add half for a rounded quotient
}

int increase_tenure(int salary, int years) {
  int percent = years >= 10 ? 10 : 7;
  return increase_percent(salary, percent);
}

// Usage
employees[i].salary += increase_tenure(employees[i].salary, employees[i].service_year);
```

Comment: Man, you are a genius! Loved the way you did it!

Comment: thank you so much, your code is amazing, i learn a lot from your coding!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use floating point number for `salary` variable as after multiplication with `0.1` and `0.07`, there will be information loss.
*You also need to change the format specifier in `printf` and `scanf` to `%f` as the variable `salary` is of type `float` now.*

Here is the code snippet to guide you.

### Employee Struct

```c
typedef struct
{
    
  char employee_name[30];
  int employee_number;
  float salary;
  int service_year
  
} Employee;
```

### Calculate Increment

```c
// Calculate the increment in salary
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(employees[i].service_year >= 10)
       employees[i].salary+=(0.1)*employees[i].salary;
    else if(employees[i].service_year >=0 && employees[i].service_year < 10)
       employees[i].salary+=(0.07)*employees[i].salary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your 3rd goal I only have created a method that receives the address of the employee struct, then I check the condition of his years of services, and finally, add the 10% or the 7%. In this approach i have directly incremented the salary when the data of the employee has been introduced, but feel free to call `increment()` whenever you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    
  char employee_name[30];
  int employee_number;
  float salary;
  int service_year
  
} Employee;
void increment (Employee * current);
int main ()
{
  int i, n = 5;

  Employee employees[n];

//Taking each employee detail as input

  printf ("Enter %d Employee Details \n \n", n);
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

      printf ("Employee %d:- \n", i + 1);
      //Name
      printf ("Name: ");
      scanf ("%s", employees[i].employee_name);
      //ID
      printf ("Id: ");
      scanf ("%d", &employees[i].employee_number);
      //Salary
      printf ("Salary: ");
      scanf ("%f", &employees[i].salary);
      //Year of service_year
      printf ("Year of Service: ");
      scanf ("%d", &employees[i].service_year);
      //printf ("Incrementing the salary according the years of service");
      increment (&employees[i]);

    }

//Displaying Employee details

  printf ("-------------- All Employees Details ---------------\n");

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

      printf ("Employee Name \t: ");
      printf ("%s \n", employees[i].employee_name);

      printf ("Employee Number \t: ");
      printf ("%d \n", employees[i].employee_number);

      printf ("Salary \t: ");
      printf ("%f \n", employees[i].salary);

      printf ("Year of Service \t: ");
      printf ("%d \n", employees[i].service_year);

      printf ("\n");
    }

  return 0;

}

void increment (Employee * current)
{
  if (current->service_year >= 10)
    current->salary += current->salary * 0.1;
  else
    current->salary += current->salary * 0.07;
}
```

One output I have obtained using random employees. for my commodity and to check if this works, the salary of all of them is 100.

```
Enter 5 Employee Details 
 
Employee 1:- 
Name: Toni
Id: 23
Salary: 100
Year of Service: 10
Employee 2:- 
Name: Pedro
Id: 15
Salary: 100
Year of Service: 5
Employee 3:- 
Name: Juan
Id: 78
Salary: 100
Year of Service: 15
Employee 4:- 
Name: Ramon
Id: 55
Salary: 100
Year of Service: 1
Employee 5:- 
Name: Ester
Id: 44
Salary: 100
Year of Service: 55
-------------- All Employees Details ---------------
Employee Name   : Toni 
Employee Number     : 23 
Salary  : 110 
Year of Service     : 10 

Employee Name   : Pedro 
Employee Number     : 15 
Salary  : 107 
Year of Service     : 5 

Employee Name   : Juan 
Employee Number     : 78 
Salary  : 110 
Year of Service     : 15 

Employee Name   : Ramon 
Employee Number     : 55 
Salary  : 107 
Year of Service     : 1 

Employee Name   : Ester 
Employee Number     : 44 
Salary  : 110 
Year of Service     : 55
```

Comment: What about the floating-point numbers? Isn't there a loss of information about multiplying with `0.1`?

Comment: @SourabhChoure: They got lucky in this case. When .1 and .07 are converted to the format most commonly used for `double`, IEEE-754 binary64, the results are slightly above .1 and .07 (e.g., 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625). Then the multiplication by a 32-bit integer yields a number slightly higher than the real-arithmetic result of multiplying by .1 or .07 or, due to rounding, the same number. If it is higher, the excess is lost when the result is truncated back to an integer. This is effectively happenstance and could not be relied on with other proportions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Wow, Thanks for enlightening me, with this amazing explanation. Shouldn't the OP use `float` instead of `int` to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have edited the post, changing the variable salary

Comment: @SourabhChoure: All fixed-size formats have issues. Using `float` or `double` can still have rounding issues. Using `int` also has rounding issues (if a 7% increase results in a fraction of a currency unit, which way should you round?). You can calculate 7% truncated to a currency unit with `x*7/100`, but what happens if `x*7` overflows? There are various solutions, using `int`, `float`, `double`, or other types, but, whichever one you choose, you have to know what the issues are and design the code to work as desired.